# React : Warning: You tried to redirect to the same route you're currently on redirect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-router-dom

I am trying to redirect user to another page but in meantime I am getting this error `Warning: You tried to redirect to the same route you're currently on redirect` . could someone please help me how to solve this problem thanks .

**Code**

```
 {userType === "admin" ? (
                  <>
                    <li className="nav-item active">
                      <Link className="nav-link" to="/users?page=1&pageSize=10">
                        Users
                      </Link>
                    </li>
                  </>
                ) : (
                  <Redirect from="/admin" to="/dashboard" exact />
                )}
```

Comment: Post the complete code with your routing.

Comment: If you render this component for `dashboard` route and the user would be an admin then you'd redirect to the same route you're already on.

Comment: Perform the condtional component rendering in a parent component.

Comment: @Clarity . Actually I want to redirect user if it not admin and redirect it to this path /dashboard from /admin path